# Determining SSC (Spread Spectrum Clocking) on Linux

Tags: clock, pci-e

Is there a Linux generic shell command to determine whether SSC is on or off on the PCIe system?

Answer (score 0):

According to *PCI Express Base Specification Rev 3.0*, SSC must be turned off, if RX and TX are operated on different `Refclk` sources. So there should be a flag to monitor and control SSC.

However, I have searched the complete (860 pages) specification, but I can't find any configuration register defined by the PCIe standard, to switch off SSC. So I assume it's vendor dependent, if even accessible by software.